# Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS: 'find' not found in PATH or not executable

Tags: bash, ubuntu, find, apt, path

I am trying to install some graphics libraries with the following command:

```
sudo apt install jpegoptim optipng
```

It however fails to run with stating the following:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  jpegoptim optipng
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 273 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/208 kB of archives.
After this operation, 625 kB of additional disk space will be used.
dpkg: warning: 'find' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: error: 1 expected program not found in PATH or not executable
Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

I then try to install `find` with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install findutils
```

But it fails to install as it says it is already installed:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
findutils is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 273 not upgraded.
```

I noticed that my `/etc/environment` file was empty and I added the following to that:

```
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

Unfortunately that has not worked either.  It stil results in:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  jpegoptim optipng
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 273 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/208 kB of archives.
After this operation, 625 kB of additional disk space will be used.
dpkg: warning: 'find' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: error: 1 expected program not found in PATH or not executable
Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

I have also tried putting the following in the `.bashrc` file:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

but it still complains about the PATH being incorrect.

Comment: Have you sourced bashrc after editing?

Comment: I have tried that and also logging out and in to the server

Comment: show me the output of `$PATH`.

Comment: `ubuntu@ip-XX-XX-XX-XX:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games`


`root@ip-XX-XX-XX-XX:~# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin`

Looks like the paths have doubled up.  I don't think that should have any adverse effects.

Comment: Does `/usr/bin/find` exist?

Comment: `ubuntu@ip-XX-XX-XX-XX:~$ which find`
`ubuntu@ip-XX-XX-XX-XX:~$ [ ! -f /usr/bin/find ] && echo "File does not exist"`
`File does not exist`
And for the root user

`root@ip-XX-XX-XX-XX:~# [ ! -f /usr/bin/find ] && echo "File does not exist"`
`File does not exist`

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install findutils
```

The 'reinstall' option allows you to re-install packages that are already installed and at the newest version.

Even if this works I would be concerned that your /usr/bin/find had previously disappeared, if it wasn't deleted by mistake then maybe your system was hacked?